# Why does my total price output keeps on getting NaN error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've done some experiments but the NaN error just doesn't go away i dont think i have any more idea 
i would like to add my room price and addon price to display the total value but it keeps getting NaN in my total display i called my function total to both js after appending the item
Here is my js code for my bookingroom

```
$(".bkng").on("click",function(event) {
              event.preventDefault();

            var id = $(this).data('room-id');
          name = $(this).data('name');
        price = $(this).data('price');
                console.log(id);


                if(id != '')

                {
                    $.ajax(
                {
                    type:"POST",
                    url : "Pages/ajax",
                    data:{id:id,
                        name:name,
                        price:price},


                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        console.dir(data);
                        if (data) {


                        var item = $('<li data-itemprice="'+price+'">'+name+' : '+price+'</li>');
                            $("#test1").html(item);
                           Total();
                        }
                        else {
                             $('#test1').append('no records found');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            });
        });
```

MY JS for addons

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".addons").on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();


        var $this = $(this);
        var id = $(this).data('addon-id');
        name = $(this).data('name');
        price = $(this).data('price');

        console.log(id);

        $(this).addClass('is-hidden');
        $('.removebtn[data-addon-id="' + id + '"]').removeClass('is-hidden');
        if(id != '')

            {

                    $.ajax(
                {
                    type:"POST",
                    url : "Pages/addonajax",
                    data:{id:id,
                        name:name,
                        price:price},


                    success:function(data)
                    {
                            console.dir(data);
                            if (data) {

                            var item = $('<li data-itemprice="'+price+'">'+name+' : '+price+'</li>');
                            $("#test4").append(item);
                               Total();

                        }
                        else {

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
      }      
});
```

my function Total

```
function Total() {

           total = 0;
         $('li').each(function(index,object){
        //Adds the price of each item to the variable: total
         total = total + Number($(object).data('itemprice'))

   });
        //Displays total of all items 
         $("#test2").html("Total:" + total);

    }
```

and my html code to display the total

```
<h3 class = "your-stay" id = "test2">Total: <span></span></h3>
```

Comment: Try with parseInt. `total = total + parseInt($(object).data('itemprice'));` Looks like it's treat as string and unable to add .

Comment: @Shree still NaN error :(

Comment: Just see on console what vale comes from. `console.log(parseInt($(object).data('itemprice'))`

Comment: it says on the console NaN 2750. the 2750 is the price of each data not the total so it displays only the price of each data. do you have any idea why?

Comment: One of your $(object).data('itemprice') return empty value .  Check with debugger.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Total() {
    var total = 0;
    $('li').each(function (index, object) {
        //Adds the price of each item to the variable: total
        var price = $(object).data('itemprice');
        if (+price)
            total = (total + (+price));
    });
    //Displays total of all items
    $("#test2").html("Total:" + total);
}
```

try this and see if it is helpful

also check in if condition be like

```
if(id){
....code
}
```